.NET app call unmanged DLL, parameters contains strange characters
I am wring a .NET app to call an unmanaged DLL(Unicode).
Below is the header for the unmanaged DLL:
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  /* __cplusplus */

//  Callback function for ProcessFileAPI. The function is called whenever progress advances.
typedef VOID (CALLBACK* LPPROGRESSPROC)(CONST BYTE btProgress, LPVOID lParam);

#pragma pack(1)

//  Options for ProcessFileAPI
typedef struct _OPTIONS1
{
    BOOL m_bOption1;
    BOOL m_bOption2;
} OPTIONS1, *LPOPTIONS1;

#pragma pack()

DWORD WINAPI ProcessFileAPI(LPCTSTR lpSrcFileName, LPCTSTR lpDstFileName, LPPROGRESSPROC lpProgressProc, LPVOID lpProgProcParam,
                           LPBOOL pbCancel, CONST LPOPTIONS1 lpOptions1);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

And the .cpp for unmanaged DLL:
extern "C"  DWORD WINAPI ProcessFileAPI(LPCTSTR lpSrcFileName, LPCTSTR lpDstFileName, LPPROGRESSPROC lpProgressProc, LPVOID lpProgProcParam,
                                       LPBOOL pbCancel, CONST LPOPTIONS1 lpOptions1)
{
    TRACE(_T("SrcFileName: %s. DstFileName: %s."), lpSrcFileName, lpDstFileName);
    return  0;
}

Below is the .NET code for the function:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SDKAPI
{
    public struct TOptions1
    {
        public bool bOption1;
        public bool bOption2;
    }   // end TOptions1

    public delegate void TProgressProc(byte btProgress, IntPtr lParam);
}

namespace SDKAPI.Units
{
    public class SDKAPI
    {
        [DllImport("SDK.DLL")]
        public static extern uint ProcessFileAPI(string lpSrcFileName, string lpDstFileName, TProgressProc pgrsproc, IntPtr lpProgProcParam, ref int pbCancel, ref TOptions1 options);

    } // end SDKAPI
}

And below is the calling of the function:
Options1.bOption1 = true;
Options1.bOption2 = false;

// Process the file
FCancel = 0;

RetCode = SDKAPI.Units.SDKAPI.ProcessFileAPI(txtSrcFile.Text, txtDstFile.Text, new SDKAPI.TProgressProc(this.ProgressProc), IntPtr.Zero, ref FCancel, ref Options1);

When calling the DLL with txtSrcFile.Text = "a" and txtDstFile.Text = "b", but I debug in the DLL and find the parameter lpSrcFileName becomes "a" then followed with many strange characters. Why?

I usually use a managed C++/CLI layer, but a C# string isn't the same as LPCTSTR. In the extern declaration, in C#, try adding [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]  before string lpSrcFileName. The default is a BStr, see here

@ChrisMM LPCTSTR isn't LPWStr either.

@alancc Did you compile the dll as Unicode or not? Add that information in your [DllImport] using the CharSet property.

@GSerg, the DLL is in Unicode.

Then use CharSet.Unicode in the function declaration.  With it missing it assumes 8-bit characters and the string turns into Chinese.

You need to find out whether the unmanaged DLL is using Unicode or not. If yes you need CharSet.Unicode otherwise CharSet.Ansi.
You also need to set the pack.
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct TOptions1
{
    public bool bOption1;
    public bool bOption2;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public delegate void TProgressProc(byte btProgress, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("SDK.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint ProcessFileAPI(
    string lpSrcFileName, string lpDstFileName, TProgressProc pgrsproc,
    IntPtr lpProgProcParam, ref bool pbCancel, [In] in TOptions1 options);


BOOL, as opposed to bool, is I4, not I1. There is UnmanagedType.Bool for that, which is the default anyway.

OK fixed that. Always confuses me those two.

The DLL is in Unicode, I have updated my question.

Some questions: 1. Since BOOL is diffferent from bool, why the codes still using bool? 2. "[In] in TOptions1 options" will cause compiler error, so I replace it with "[In] TOptions1 options" but the passed values are always incorrect.

bool is in C#, there is only one type. The question was only what to map it to in the marshalling. What compiler error do you get? Works fine in .NET 8 https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMe2Px If you are using .NET Framework then change it back to ref. Do not use it without either ref or in otherwise it won't work.

I use C# in Visual Studio 2008, and the compiler sees to be "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5". So I think it is .net framework.

I'm assuming you realize VS 2008 went out of support in 2018, and that .NET 3.5 while still supported is missing many many performance and usability fixes and improvements, I strongly recommend you upgrade pronto. In future make sure you tag [tag:.net-3.5] because people won't realize.

I see. I have add .net-3.5 tag. Also can I use uint as the type for C++ BOOL? Since uint in C# is 4-byte, which exactly match C++ BOOL.

Yes you could if you want
